# Can't get rid of dotted outline in Firefox links?

Tags: css, firefox, outline, dotted-line

I have a list full of a imgs:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#"><img src="test.png" /></a</li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="test.png" /></a</li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="test.png" /></a</li>
(...)
</ul>
```

When I click them in Firefox, there's dotted outline (who the heck invented that and why? so ugly!).

I want to get rid of them, but style "outlines" etc. doesn't seem to work, I've tried all of options below:

```
#ul li img:active {
    -moz-outline-style: none;
    -moz-focus-inner-border: 0; 
    outline: none;
    outline-style: none;
}     

#ul li img:focus {
    -moz-outline-style: none;
    -moz-focus-inner-border: 0; 
    outline: none;
    outline-style: none;
}

 #ul li img a:active {
        -moz-outline-style: none;
        -moz-focus-inner-border: 0; 
        outline: none;
        outline-style: none;
    }     

    #ul li img a:focus {
        -moz-outline-style: none;
        -moz-focus-inner-border: 0; 
        outline: none;
        outline-style: none;
    }
```

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your problem in your question?

Comment: "who the heck invented that and why? so ugly!" Accessibility. Because you need to indicate which element is focused when you are tabbing down the website with a keyboard. Don't just remove it with `outline: 0` - think of an alternative for those users.

Comment: @Yi Jiang, that's what the anchor states are there for. A good developer should use a:active, a:focus, and optionally a:visited for accesibility - it doesn't always have to show an ugly outline. It works for tabbing too. Oh and I'm pretty sure it's turned off by default in all the other browsers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to apply the styles to the `<a>` tag (your latter two CSS rules are wrong because you've put the `<a>` tag inside `<img>`.

This works for me:

```
a:active,
a:focus {
  outline: none;
  -moz-outline-style: none;
}
```

Or, for only inside the element with ID `ul` (not the best name, by the way):

```
#ul a:active,
#ul a:focus {
  outline: none;
  -moz-outline-style: none;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
a:active,
a:focus {
  outline: none;
  -moz-outline-style: none;
}
```

works for me in FF22

Answer (score 4):

**outline: 0** should do it and it should be applied on the `<a>` element, which is not actually a child of `<img />`. `<img />` is a child of `<a>` so your css should read:

```
#ul li a {
    outline: 0;
}
```