# Dashed outline around HorizontalLayout in Vaadin

Tags: css, vaadin

I have found a problem. When i click on HorizontalLayout (which contains MenuBar) then dashed border (in Firefox) or solid border #CC540A (in Chrome) appears around it. In IE7 and Opera everything is ok - it does not occur there.

screenshot available here:
http://img257.imageshack.us/img257/5056/problemvaadin.png
or here
http://www.pl.image-share.com/ipng-27-12.html
or in attachments to this topic

code snippet:

```
HorizontalLayout rightContent = new HorizontalLayout();

rightContent.setWidth("995px");
rightContent.setHeight("117px");
rightContent.addStyleName(IEhrCssStyles.MAIN_HEADER_LAYOUT_RIGT_CONTENT);
MenuBar menuBar = createMenuBar();
rightContent.addComponent(menuBar);
rightContent.setComponentAlignment(menuBar,Alignment.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
```

Any ideas ?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: Looks like the standard "focused" outline. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707918/cant-get-rid-of-dotted-outline-in-firefox-links (I'm not familiar with Vaadin, so I can't tell you where to place the CSS)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding this line of css to either the layout or the menubar should fix it for both problems:

```
outline: 0;
```

(may also be outline:none but if I recall correctly both should work.)